# Как перенести сайт на VPS другого хостера?

Tags: хостинг, vps

Есть сайт, база которого весит 2 ТБ. Как можно перенести сайт к другому хостеру, если на компьютер такую базу скачать нельзя из-за объема SSD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Способ 1 (простой, но долгий и с простоем): Сделать дамп БД в файл, скачать файл на другой сервер, развернуть дамп в БД.
Способ 2 (сложный, но почти без простоя): Сделать репликацию БД на новый сервер, переключиться на реплику.
Что касается кода самого сайта, тут должно быть проще.